# How to access the elements of the LiveData list "Livedata<List<Model>> in Kotlin?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-livedata, android-jetpack

In Java we access the first element of `Livedata<List<Book>>` books using `books[0]`, how to do that in Kotlin?

I have already tried everything.

//Java code
`books[0];`

//Kotlin
//`books[0]` throws error

Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch:
@InlineOnly public inline operator fun <@OnlyInputTypes K, V> Map.get(key: Int): Category? defined in kotlin.collections

Comment: "In Java we access the first element of Livedata<List<Book>> books using books[0]" -- what, exactly, is `books`? Is `books` a `LiveData<List<Book>>`? Is `books` a `List<Book>`? Is `books` something else? Because `books[0]` works for a `List<Book>` but does not work for a `LiveData<List<Book>>`. You might wish to edit your question and provide a more complete example of how you are declaring `books` and where it comes from.

Comment: If `books` is `LiveData<List<Book>>` then you can use `books.value?.get(0)` for first element. But LiveData should be observed to access data as `books.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { books -> books[0]})`.

Answer (score 0):

You could try 
`books.get(0)`

Kotlin allows you to some operators on types, one is infix, such as the `+` as it is between to expresses/values.  I think the error is telling you you cant access `books` using array notation.